# r - trying to run knitr chunk - Error: unexpected input in "<<"

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

this is my first question here so please forgive if it is unclear/messy.
I'm trying to reproduce the example in this [page](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/07/09/making-use-of-external-r-code-in-knitr-and-r-markdown/), reading chunks from an .R script and running them in an .Rmd markdown using knitr. The `read_chunk()` command seems to execute properly, but when I try to reference the chunks with the `<<some_chunk>>` notation R gives me: **Error: unexpected input in "<<".**
I have W10x64 and I'm using R v 3.5.1 with RStudio v1.1.456

This is the content of the .R script:

```
# This is our external R script called example.R
# We're adding two chunks variablesXY and plotXY

## @knitr variablesXY

x<-1:100
y<-x+rnorm(100)
head(data.frame(x,y))

## @knitr plotXY

plot(x,y)
```

And this is inside the .Rmd markdown (I got the error when I try to call `<<variablesXY>>`):

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
```
# read chunk (does not run code)
```{r echo=FALSE}
read_chunk('example.R')
```
# run the variablesXY chunk and use the variables it creates
```{r first}
<<variablesXY>>
head(data.frame(x,y))

```
# run the plotXY chunk and create the plot
```{r second}
<<plotXY>>
```
````

Comment: I'm not sure that guide is entirely accurate. I would probably follow the style used with the example from the developer at https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/

Comment: You should be able to knit the whole document, but you cannot runt he code chunk interactively inside the RStudio IDE. The IDE currently does not support the `<<>>` syntax.